# C Programming Strings

Tags: c

How to fetch first two bytes from the string "DDMMYYHHMMSS" and fill the below structure.

```
mytime.tm_sec  = SS;   // Seconds      (0-59)
mytime.tm_min  = MM;   // Minutes      (0-59)
mytime.tm_hour = HH;   // Hours        (0-23)
mytime.tm_mday = YY;   // Day of Month (1-31)
mytime.tm_mon  = MM;   // Month        (0-11)
mytime.tm_year = DD;   // Year         (no. of years since 1900)
```

Comment: The first two bytes?  That means only `DD`.  Is that really what you want?  If so, do you want to assume the current month, year, etc.?  You could initialize using `localtime` and then override using the parts you want to change.

Comment: @stanigator no it is not

Comment: [How to ask and answer homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). 1 Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. 2. Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation. 3. Admit that the question is homework. 4. Never use code you don't understand.

Comment: @Mikel not only DD the consecutive values has to be fetched too.

Comment: What specific problems are you having with @maverik's suggestion? Perhaps that would be a better question.

Comment: Well I am a Web Programmer and need to write a piece of c code in the backend which is why I have to post this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m assuming this is [homework](/questions/tagged/homework), so I won’t give you the full answer.

Let's split this problem into bits.

1) Given a string, do you know how to extract a sub-string? *E.g.*, can you figure out how to accomplish this:

```
char sample[] = "DDMMYYHHMMSS";
char *dd;
// code you need to figure out
printf("%s", dd); // should print “DD”
```

Hint: Look up `strncpy()`.

2) Once you’ve figured that out, do you know how to convert a string of digits to a number?  *E.g.*, can you accomplish this:

```
char dd[] = "32";
int mday;
// code you need to figure out
printf("%d", mday); // should print “32”
```

Hint: Look up `sscanf()` & `atoi()`.

At this point, combining those two techniques should be straightforward.  By all means ask more if you need more help.

Answer (score 3):

May be I don;t understand the question, but why can't you do the following:

```
assert(strlen(timestring) == 12);

char ss[3];
strncpy(ss, &timestring[10], 2);
mytime.tm_sec = atoi(ss);

// same for others
```

UPD: No, stop right now. I forget about `strptime` (check man pages). It should help you

Answer (score 1):

In C, one `char` is one byte, and a string is an array of `char`s. You need to take the `char`s at indices 0 and 1. Then you can convert the value into `int`s if necessary.